# Parse CSV into key value pair

Tags: tcl

I have a csv file which has hostname and attached serial numbers. I want to create a key value pair with key being hostname and value being the list of serial numbers. The serial numbers can be one or many.

For example:

```
A, 1, 2, 3, 4
B, 5, 6
C, 7, 8, 9
D, 10
```

I need to access key `A` and get `{1 2 3 4}` as output. And if I access D i should get `{10}`

How should I do this? As the version of TCL i am using doesn't support any packages like CSV and I also won't be able to install it as it is in the server, So I am looking at a solution which doesn't include any packages.

For now, I am splitting the line with `\n` and then I process each element. Then I split the elements with "," and then I get the host name and serial numbers in a list. I then use the 0th index of the list as hostname and remaining values as serial numbers. Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require csv
package require struct::queue

set filename "file.csv"
set fh [open $filename r]

set q [struct::queue]
csv::read2queue $fh $q
close $fh

set data [dict create]
while {[$q size] > 0} {
    set values [lassign [$q get] hostname]
    dict set data $hostname [lmap elem $values {string trimleft $elem}]
}

dict for {key value} $data {
    puts "$key => $value"
}
```

then

```
$ tclsh csv.tcl
A => 1 2 3 4
B => 5 6
C => 7 8 9
D => 10
```

Comment: Didn't Rohit ask for sth without `package req csv`? Not that this was particularly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The repeated recommendation given here is to use the CSV package for this purpose. See also the answer by @glenn-jackman. If unavailable, the time is better invested in obtaining it at your server side.

To get you started, however, you might want to adopt something along the lines of:

```
set dat {
    A, 1, 2, 3, 4
    B, 5, 6
    C, 7, 8, 9
    D, 10
}

set d [dict create]

foreach row [split [string trim $dat] \n] {
    set row [lassign [split $row ,] key]
    dict set d [string trim $key] [concat {*}$row]
}

dict get $d A
dict get $d D
```

Be warned, however, such hand-knitted solutions typically only serve their purpose when you have full control of the data being processed and its representation. Again, time is better invested by obtaining the CSV package.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and got it working. Thanks again for your inputs. Yes, I know csv package would be easy but I cannot install it in server/product.

```
set multihost "host_slno.csv"
set fh1 [open $multihost r]
set data [read -nonewline $fh1]
close $fh1
set hostslnodata [ split $data "\n" ]
set hostslno [dict create];

foreach line $hostslnodata {
  set line1 [join [split $line ", "] ]
  puts "$line1"
  if {[regexp {([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)\s+(.*)} $line1 match hostname serial_numbers]} {
    dict lappend hostslno $hostname $serial_numbers
  }
}
puts [dict get $hostslno]
```

Comment: Hi Rohit! Thx for sharing, but this is rather a confirmation, not an answer. You might want to accept the answer that helped find your working solution?

Answer (score 0):

The sourcecode from the csv package is available.  If you are unable to install the full csv package, you can include the code from here:

http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/artifact/2898cd911697ecdb

If you still can't use that option, then stripping out all the whitespace and splitting on "," is required.

An alternative to the earlier answers is using string map:

```
set row [split [string map  {" " ""} $row ] ,]
```

The string map will remove all spaces, and then split on ","

Once you have converted the lines of text into valid tcl lists:

```
A 1 2 3 4
B 5 6
C 7 8 9
D 10
```

Then you can use the lindex and lrange commands to pluck off all the pieces.

```
foreach row $data {
    set server [lindex $row 0]
    set serial_numbers [lrange $row 1 end]
    dict set ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```
set hostslno [dict create]
set multihost "host_slno.csv"

set fh1 [open $multihost]
while {[gets $fh line] >= 0} {
    set numbers [lassign [regexp -inline -all {[^\s,]+} $line] hostname]
    dict set hostslno $hostname $numbers
}
close $fh1

puts [dict get $hostslno A]
```